# Title in Windows 10 Task Bar changes when not on main form in winforms c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a standard Winforms Application.  When the user is on the Main Form, the caption in the task bar for the program matches the Main Form's caption

However, as soon as the user goes into a form that I load from the main form, using ShowDialog, the caption on the taskbar goes to the name of the application

How can I prevent this from happening?

The Assembly.Title is being ignored

Cheers

Paul

Comment: That does not answer my question

Comment: @CaiusJard yes that worked thanks!  Please can you add that as an answer then I can accept it for others

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set `ShowInTaskbar = false` on the dialog form it should mean that Windows takes the text of some other form in your app that is still allowed to show. As you have only one other form (at the moment) this will be the main form text